# How can I inject variable values into the sql being passed to "database.ExecuteWithResults()"

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Using the [powershell example from msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205775.aspx) as a reference and assuming I'm talking to a sql server database:

```
$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$db = $srv.Databases.Item("AdventureWorks2012")
$db.ExecuteNonQuery("CHECKPOINT")
$ds = $db.ExecuteWithResults("SELECT * FROM Person.Address")
Foreach ($t in $ds.Tables)
{
   Foreach ($r in $t.Rows)
   {
      Foreach ($c in $t.Columns)
      {
          Write-Host $c.ColumnName "=" $r.Item($c)
      }
   }
}
```

How can I inject variable values into the sql being passed to `$db.ExecuteWithResults` like I can do with sqlcmd as below:

```
sqlcmd -v person="name" -i c:\testscript.sql
```

The example sql might look something like this:

```
declare @PersonsName varchar(100) = '$(person)';

select * from Persons
where name = @PersonsName;
```

I cannot see any options to include this type of injection when using `ExecuteWithResults` other than doing a nasty string replace on the sql itself?

Ignoring any sql injection issues that this could potentially open up here, I dont want to get into a discussion about security around this question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteWirthResults method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.executewithresults.aspx) shows only string and string collection overloads so you won't be able to execute a parameterized query. In PowerShell, you could simply specify the variable name in the query text, which PS will replace with the actual string at run time:

```
$ds = $db.ExecuteWithResults("select * from Persons where name = '$person';")
```

Consider using SqlClient rather than SMO to execute queries so that you can execute parameterized queries:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("CHECKPOINT", $connection)
$connection.Open()
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person.Person WHERE LastName = @PersonsName;";
$person = "Duffy";
[void](($command.Parameters.Add("@PersonsName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 100)).Value = $person);
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command)
[void]$da.Fill($dt)
$dt | Format-Table
```