# Inserting Null value into SQL Server using PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, null

I don't want to insert a modified date into my SQL Server database for this particular event and I want to pass NULL value but it inserting "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" in the `modifiedDate` column instead of just NULL value.

DB

```
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
```

PS Script

```
$null1 = $NULL
$EventId2 = Get-EventId 30

Set-UsrHistory $EventId2.Event_Id $IN $ID $UPN $OneDrive $Mailbox $CreatedDate $null1

Function Get-EventId($EventId) {
    $query = "select Event_Id from List_of_Events where Event_Id = '$EventId'"
    $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
    return $result.Tables[0]
}

Function Set-UsrHistory($EvtId, $IN, $ID, $UPN, $OneDrive, $Mailbox, $CreatedDate, $ModifiedDate) {
    $query = "insert into User_History (Event_Id,IN,ID,UPN,OneDrive, Mailbox,CreatedDate, ModifiedDate) VALUES   ('$EvtId',$IN,'$ID','$UPN','$OneDrive', '$Mailbox','$CreatedDate', '$ModifiedDate')"
 
    $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
}
```

`Get-EventId` function get the Event Id from my Event table and `Set-UsrHistory` function does that querying logic and insert to my History table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok sorry, I just added the function. pls check. thanks

Comment: If you output the value of `$query` you should see the error is because you have manually enclosed "$null" with single quotes (and try `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '');`. If you use proper parameters you won't have this problem (and you protect yourself from SQL injection and dealing with string values that contain `'`).

Comment: sorry I'm kinda confuse, what and where should I change?

Comment: @aasenomad you need to update the function to test if either of the parameter arguments are `$null` (eg. `if($null -eq $ModifiedDate)`) and then make sure you place the literal word `NULL` in place of `'$ModifiedDate'` in the query string.

Comment: You need to parameterize this properly otherwise you leave yourself open to **dangerous** injection problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795603/how-can-i-inject-variable-values-into-the-sql-being-passed-to-database-executew

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[System.DBNull]::Value` rather than powershell's `$null`:

```
$null1 = [System.DBNull]::Value
```